# Firestore Rules - Array validation

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am using firestore for creating a food blog where users can upload posts and like it.
Call it facebook for food.

Below I will give you summary of 2 firestore database collections which are going to be used in my question.

First is Users - where the document name is based on UID and it stores information like, username/emailID
Second is Posts - where the document name is based on UID, however in the structure of the collection
It has a column named as "Likes" which is an array object. This stores 2 values : 1. Name of the person who liked the post and 2. UID of the person who liked the post.
Please find the structure of LIKES column in posts document below :
[image: Structure of LIKES column within POSTS document]

I am trying to add more validations to the likes part of the document.
However, from postman it is possible to change the name of the person who is liking the post.

The logic of the restrictions has to be on 2 things.

1. LIKES - UID should be present in my users collection. Also, UID in LIKES column shouldn't be changeable.
2. LIKES - Name should not be allowed to be changed.

I tried a of way of doing it but it doesnt work :

```
exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.resource.data.likes[request.resource.data.likes.size() -1].userId))
```

What it does is checks the last UID of person liking that document. However, in this scenario if there are more than 1 Likes, the name/uid could be altered for the ones which were present earlier.
Not a very efficient way.

Also, Loops dont work in rules so I cant loop it up to get it.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Please let me know if there are any more snippets which would be required.

Comment: Can you clarify the use case? What should be allowed and what not allowed? The presented part of rule is checking if  users document exits.  But if I understand correctly, if user has uid, it has to be in the database already, so it's always true... except empty list...

Comment: The basic use case is from backend no one should be able to modify the username and userid of the person who is liking the post. 

What is happening is - this is working fine from UI. 
But I try to hit PATCH call on the likes column of the post - the Name of the person can be changed. We need to restrict that.

Comment: OK, but security rules work on whole document, so you will not restrict only one field, but whole document. So if you restrict it you will be not able to write new likes...

Comment: There needs to be a way out - this would be a big bug. Also, it might lead to some other complications in applications where financial transactions are happening. 
If there were looping facility available in rules, I would have been able to achieve what I need.

Comment: what is mentioned UI? if it's working there, why you cannot do it the same way?